# How to update the `ListView` according to `ArrayList`?

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

I have an array of contacts that I am constantly updating. I want my `ListView` to update with my contacts.

Should I use an `Adapter` for that? I cant find much information about `Adapter` online, so how do I make sure that my listview always has the contents of my `Array`? (I have been researching this for 4 and a half hours!)

For example, if I have an array that has the contents `"apple"` and `"orange"`, then my list should also say `"apple"` and `"orange"`.

If I chose to remove `"apple"`, then my list should say just `"orange"`. Basically, my list should always be the same as my array.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394176/android-populating-a-listview-with-array-items), but then how would I go about deleting and adding more items to my list?

Comment: Refer my  solution for fetching the contact from contact list...   http://stackoverflow.com/a/35077124/3946958

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha Thanks, but that is not what I'm trying to do. I have specific contacts in my arraylist, that the user has already picked using an intent. I want to only keep the contacts from **my** arraylist into the listview. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Create a ListAdapter something like this.

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


  private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList();

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return names.length;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int location) {
    return names[location];
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView listViewNgoName, listViewDistance, listViewRating, listViewAbout, ngoIcon;
  }

  public MyListAdapter(
      ArrayList names) {
    this.names = names;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
     // Write code for instantiating a row based view.
    return convertView;
  }
}
```

Now in your Activity

```
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList();
    names.add("oranges");
    names.add("apple");
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(names);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Lets suppose you need to update the listview on the button click. ie. on button click the values in your array gets changed and you wanted to update the listView.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        names.add("payaya");
        names.add("grapes");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
    });
```

I have not written the entire code. Just a head start for you.

Answer (score 0):

so, You have to notify your ListView adapter that the data has changed.

```
listViewAdapater.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

hope, this would work

Comment: How do I make the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an **Array**, I recommend using **ArrayList**.

The advantage of ArrayList over Array is that arrays require fixed size. So if you are initializing an Array

```
String names[] = new String[10];
```

the size is 10, and when you set to ListView, the ListView will show 10 lists, even though there is name only in 8 array positions

Where as if you use ArrayList, you don't have to worry about size, since it can scale up and down

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add("Raul");
names.add("Khan");
names.remove(1);
```

add() adds an item to the list, while remove() removes an item.

With respect to your answer, say you have an ArrayList of items

and when you have a new item to add to the list, just add it to your ArrayList with the add() method, and finally call **notifyDataSetChanged()** on your **ArrayAdapter.**

***And YES, you have to use an ArrayAdapter like this***

```
ArrayList<String> namesList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, namesList);
```

And when you have changes to the list, ie when you add items to your list, call **notifyDataSetChanged() on arrayAdapter.**

---

Comment: Thanks, what is `simple_list_item_1`?

Comment: That is android defaults for spinner layout

Comment: Wait, what spinner layout? Now I'm really confused, I thought it was just my listview I was changing?

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong, what I meant is ListView layout. Spinner also got something similar.

Comment: So just to get things clear, I don't modify the actual adapter, I only modify the arraylist. Then, I call notifydatasetchanged to modify the layout that the adapter corresponds to?

Comment: Yup. like you have a arraylist with 5 names, and the listview is showing those 5, now you add one more to your arraylist, then call notifyDataSetChanged() to see the ListView update to show 6 items.

Comment: Okay, thats exactly what I want! I'm a little confused from Anshul's answer (the one below yours). Do I need to extend a class or something? Thanks!

Comment: Nope, you don't. If you are extending from a class you will get finer control over your items. But in your case, I don't think it is required

Answer (score 0):

use `ArrayList` instead of `Array[]`, you don't need to initialize size for `ArrayList` so it is more flexible than `Array[]`. and it will automatically scale up or down if you `add` or `delete` items inside

Answer (score 0):

I usually have a method called `setData(List<whatever> data)` in my `Adapter`. My `Adapter` is let's say in an `Activity`. When In my activity I obtain an updated array from wherever, I call `setData()` with the new array containing the updated array.

In my Adapter I have a field defined like: `private List<Whatever> mItems`. I use this field in the `getCount()` method of the `Adapter` to obtain the list items, basically I use this list to populate the `ListView`.

What I do in the `setdata()` is assign `data` to `mItems` and I call `notifyDataSetchanged()` which refreshes the `ListView` and this time it will use the newly set data values, so everything updates to the appropriate state.

**UPDATE**

I don't have quick access to an adapter for a `ListView` but the one below should do, it's for a `ViewPager`, but the principle is the same:

```
public class AdapterTweets extends PagerAdapter {
    private List<Tweet> mItems;

    // [...]

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems == null ? 0 : mItems.size();
    }

    // [...]

    public void setData(List<Tweet> items) {
        mItems = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense. Can you provide an example, I am still confused on the adapter part. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the post, please check it out ... You call `setData` once you have the new list of items you want to display and it will refresh the list. :)